# PHP prevent client timeout for long requests

Tags: c#, php, http

I am currently building a very small kind of API in php. Depending on the data the client is requesting, it can take hours until the data is collected and can be returned. My client is currently a C# program. It gets a timeout after some time.

**Is there a way in php to notify the client that the server is still working?**

- I do not want to increase the clients timeout span
- I do not want to write some white spaces to prevent the time out. This would damage the format of the response (csv file) and would require to send the header before being sure that everything worked
- Wikipedia lists the status code `102 Processing`, which notifies the client that the server is still working. This is exactly what I need. Does somebody know how to send that without canceling the execution of the script?
- If you think I need to do this with threading, I can try that. But it looks like some work and I would prefer a more simple way

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why don't you just add an animation that shows onclick of something?

Comment: It is unclear what kind of timeout you're getting here. Please provide the exact error message you got from PHP.

Comment: Why dont you just flush your buffer on each piece of data? You could send each piece of string that compose your final string by using buffer

Comment: Its not a timeout in php. The problem is that the client is waiting but not getting anything.

Comment: "prevent client timeout" seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Guilherme Ferreira I can't send any data before the php has processed everything. The php querys a database and then has to process every result.

Comment: Change the C# program. Seriously that's like 1 line of code.

Comment: What line of code should i change? The timeout? I think that is not a nice idea. When some problems with the connection occur, the program might wait for ever (or very long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in my opinion is to return a url that the client can poll to check if the result is ready.

This is how it should behave precisely: http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/

Comment: It's more complicated than I hoped, but it seems to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I will, but I'm still hoping for something easier. Thou it's not likely :p